# Separating WebApi Help component from Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I would like to separate WebApi help component from the actual API project.

The main reason of separating these two components so I can deploy this separately as help.webapi.com/ and also it does not require modifications so I can leave it as is.

I did tried to implement this model by spitting out the xml document from WebApi project to WebApi helper project. However it did not worked as expected.

It show blank documentation.

Please advise.